# Disappear variable name in console.log()

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have a definition for obj with key  -

```
var Row = function Row () {
            this.a = 1  ; 
        }
console.log(new Row());
```

When I execute it I get in the console  -

```
Row {a: 1}
```

How could I get the same but with no the variable name , mean   -

```
{a: 1}
```

I using Chrome , whether it depends on the browser ?

[Here Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/6jyq2bxm/)

Comment: Why do you want this? Why do you care how `console.log()` prints its data? If you're looking to convert your object to JSON, use `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0):

'Row' in front is specifying the type. In your case, you have named your function 'Row', which is why you are seeing 'Row' in the log. This is to make it easier for you to debug your program and it shouldn't cause any harm to you.

```
var Row = function () {
    this.a = 1;
}

var myRow = new Row();
myRow.a // this will give you your 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I'm understanding but here:

```
function Row () {
    this.a = 1  ; 
}
```

is the constructor (a function tha "create objects"), so when you call

```
console.log(new Row());
```

you are creating an instance of "Row" **class** and logging to javascript's console.
So the statement

```
var Row = function Row () ...
```

is defining the "Row" **class** and assigning it to
Row **variable**.

You can use **objects literals** in javascript and create anonymous objects in the form:

```
{key: value}
```

example:

```
var foo = {a:10, b:20, c:30}
```

and accessing it

```
console.log(foo.a); // will log "10"
```

**Objects or instances** and **classes with their constructors** functions are different things.